# Convert Table column to another table

Tags: php, foreach, html-table

I have a html table like below,

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><th>Manufacturer</th><th>Model Number</th><th>Description</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>Frigidaire</td>
<td><a href="/parts-for-frigidaire-fef368ccbb.html">FEF368CCBB</a></td>
<td>Frg(v1) / Electric Range</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Frigidaire</td>
<td><a href="/parts-for-frigidaire-fef377cfbb.html">FEF377CFBB</a></td>
<td>Frg(v1) / Electric Range</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Frigidaire</td>
<td><a href="/parts-for-frigidaire-fef368ccbf.html">FEF368CCBF</a></td>
<td>Frg(v1) / Electric Range</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Frigidaire</td>
<td><a href="/parts-for-frigidaire-fef377cfbd.html">FEF377CFBD</a></td>
<td>Frg(v1) / Electric Range</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Frigidaire</td>
<td><a href="/parts-for-frigidaire-fef368ccba.html">FEF368CCBA</a></td>
<td>Frg(v1) / Electric Range</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Frigidaire</td>
<td><a href="/parts-for-frigidaire-fef368ccbc.html">FEF368CCBC</a></td>
<td>Frg(v1) / Electric Range</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want all second column values to be created another table like below. (3 columns)

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>FEF368CCBB</td>
<td>FEF377CFBB</td>
<td>FEF368CCBF</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>FEF377CFBD</td>
<td>FEF368CCBA</td>
<td>FEF368CCBC</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to do using foreach, but it becomes complicated and messy now.

How can I do this in php? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please try following snippet of jQuery which will read all values from second cell of each row and create new table at the end of your webpage.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var html = '<table>';
      $('tr').each(function(){
        var cellVALUE = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2) a").html();
        if($(this).find("td:nth-child(2) a").length > 0){
        html += '<tr><td>'+cellVALUE+'</td></tr>';
      }
        console.log(cellVALUE);
      });
      html += '</table>';
      $('body').append(html); // append this string wherever you want to create table.
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can we do this in php

Comment: Yes, you can do in php because this is the jquery function.